# OpsHub VSOnline Migration - Migration Halted - Read Timeout

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I've been using OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility over the last week to move projects to VSO.

One of our larger projects ran for about 36 hours and after all revisions and changesets have passed, I'm getting a Migration Failed result.

Under the Work Item section I'm seeing a "Migration Halted" link, with the attached screenshot.

[image: OpsHub Migration Failed Screenshot]

I've restarted the servers, cleared the TFS Caches, etc. If I start the migration again it takes a long time (about half an hour or more) before it fails again with the same result.

I really don't want to re-run the whole thing for another 36 hours only to run into the same issue again.

What to do?

Comment: Your migration seems to be completed as you can see that the count of revision passed for workitem and version control have reached the total revision count. However for further debugging the issue can you please share log files from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs directory. Zip all the log files and send it to ovsmu@opshub.com Please mention stackoverflow url reference in mail so that we can relate it with your thread. Thanks, OpsHub Support

Comment: @OpshubInc. These log files are almost 0.5GB in size - though I'm sure it'll compress well. Apologies, but I'm under pressure to get this done since 3 days allocated for migration has now become 8 days and counting due to the slow nature of the tool. I have managed to get around this issue (as per answer below) though. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking my queue from the phrase "Test Result" in the error message, I ended up working around the above issue by doing the following:

1. Reduced the build history by deleting old builds we definitely no longer needed and made sure to also delete all the attachments (like test results) from the builds I was able to delete.
2. Reduced the Test Result data by cleaning up attachments using the TFS PowerTools Test Attachment Cleaner tool. (We have this project since TFS2008 where a lot attachments were included with automated builds than since TFS 2012). The following link was particularly useful in this regard : [Guide to reduce TFS database growth using the Test Attachment Cleaner](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2011/11/15/guide-to-reduce-tfs-database-growth-using-the-test-attachment.aspx)
3. While I was at it, I also cleaned out other "non-test result" attachments. (Not sure if this has any impact on resolving this particular issue.

After the above actions, I re-started the same migration and after a long while (~45 mins) it completed successfully.

The following supplemental link is interesting too : [When to use the Test Attachment Cleaner and when not](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2014/03/07/when-to-use-the-test-attachments-cleaner-and-when-not/)